# Best way to get all words like @*@ from a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, linq

I have a string like "@1234@ == val1 && @2312@ != val2". I want to get 1234 and 2312 which are embedded using '@' separated into an array. The string can contain more than one items embedded using '@'.

**update**: will contain only integer values between '@'.

**update2**:valid input string which can occur are "@some int value@ == val1" or similar kind of string separated with '&&' or '||'
sample input strings:

```
              "@234@ == val1",
              "@3456@ == 345 && @34563@ != 'Y'",
              "@1234@ != val1 || @1234@ != val2 || @1234@ != val3"
```

what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: use Regular Expressions.

Comment: What does it mean "similar kind of string separated with '&&' or '||'"?

Comment: @CuongLe updated question by adding sample inputs

Comment: @Jom: With your update, I delete my second Linq, the first one is simply correct.

Comment: @jom those 3 are the **only** valid inputs right!

Comment: @CuongLe please include that also. May some one will benefit in future.

Comment: @Anirudha No. many similar strings are there.

Comment: @Jom: Updated as your request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using LINQ:

```
 var list = input.Split(new[] { '@' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 var result = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Length / 2)
                        .Select(i => list.ElementAt(i*2));
```

---

In case your input like:

```
 "@12@@34@ == val1 && @2312@ != val2"
```

You can use this below Linq:

```
var list = input.Split(new[] { "==", "!=", "&&", "||" }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Length/2)
            .Select(i => list.ElementAt(i*2).Trim())
            .Select(s => s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2));
```

Comment: you should add  .ToList() in the end of result.

Comment: in my question adjacent @ will not be present. is this work fine then?

Comment: valid input string which can occur are "@some int value@ == val1" or similar kind of string separated with '&&' or '||'

Answer (score 5):

try:(include **signed** value)

```
//string patt = "@(?<value>.*?)@";
// string patt = "@(?<value>\\d*?)@";  //  just number values (if there should be an integer use + instead of *)

//string patt = "@(?<value>[+|-]?\\d*?)@";
//string str = "@1234@ == val1 && @-2312@ != val2 && @+23@ != val3";


string patt = "@(?<value>[+|-]?\\d+?)@\\s[==|!=].*?(&&|\\|\\||$){1}";
string str = "@1234@ == val1 && @-2312@ != val2 && @+78@ != val3 || @45@ == 446";

Regex r = new Regex(patt);

string str = "@1234@ == val1 && @2312@ != val2";
MatchCollection  mc = r.Matches(str);

List<string> lst = new List<string>();
foreach (Match item in mc)
{
  string value = item.Groups["value"].Value;
  lst.Add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> l=new List<int>();    
string s="@1@ == val1 && @2@ != val2 || @3@ == val1";    
Regex r=new Regex(@"(?<=@)[\d\s]+(?=@\s(==|!=).*?(&&|\|\||$){1})");
foreach(Match m in r.Matches(s))
{
l.AddRange(Regex.Split(m.Value,@"(?=\d)").Where(i=>i!="").Select(i=>int.Parse(i.Replace(" ",""))).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression you should use:

```
(?<=@)[0-9]+(?=@)
```